# Rails form_tag spanning partial and ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using a :partial for the start of a "form_tag" and the "end" in a different :partial gave

"compile error" and "syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND".

Changing the "form_tag" to a standard HTML "form" tag fixes that but gives "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
<%= token_tag %>
```

just after the HTML form tag fixes issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because form_tag is a block and the end must be contained in the same file. For example, the following code is impossible:

**foo.rb**

```
 def some_method
   puts "test"
 require 'end'
```

**end.rb**

```
 end
```

This is due the order in which the code is evaluated.